# Interpret the pairwise comparison plot from SPSS

Tags: data-visualization, spss, nonparametric, paired-comparisons, kruskal-wallis-test

For my user study, I am trying to find out to what extent people prefer to move by foot. They had the option to rank their preference for 'walking', 'jogging' and 'running' for a several amount of questions. Now I want to interpret the data by means of a Kruskal-Wallis test (`Analyze -> Non Parametric Test -> Independent samples`).

The following analysis gives me pairwise comparisons. However, I do not understand how the pairwise comparisons' plot has been created when I look at the table below it. How is the plot from the pairwise comparison generated when looking at the table below the plot?

[image: table overview]
[image: rejection of null hypothesis]
[image: boxplots]
[image: Pairwised comparison plot]

Comment: I psesume the very plot is drawn by some sort of multidimensional scaling or neural net. It doesn't bother me _how_ it was drawn, really. Does it, for you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has not responded to questions and it has been years.